# When does QuerySnapshot notify its listener?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I didn't see in any document that tell me when does `QuerySnapshot` emit new snapshot, when any document in this query change? when any data in collection change? or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a snapshot listener:

1. It emits an event right away when you first attach that listener with a snapshot of the current data that it is listening to.
2. It then emits another snapshot whenever there is a change to any of the data it listens to.

In your callback, you can always seen the current snapshot of all data by accessing the [`QuerySnapshot.docs` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docs.html). If you want to only check the changes, you can the use the [`QuerySnapshot.docChanges` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docChanges.html) instead.

Comment: your 2. mean when any data in collection change or when any data in documents in that query change?

Comment: It depends on what you are listening to. If you're listening to the entire collection, then it fires an event when any data in the collection changes. If you're listening to a query, it fires an event whenever any data in the query changes (including a new document being matched by that query). I recommend giving it a try in code, as it typically soon will make sense when you see it in action.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was actually looking for this exact answer. Glad you brought up the second point. I realized that since I was using query snapshot listener on my iOS app, anytime anything on my web app updated, the iOS version updated immediately. I realized this might be super expensive. Do you know how can I avoid this(second point you've written) from happening my app? Should I use some other get() command in swift? Would appreciate a response. thanks!